# Bukkit Part of my code works only for the first person

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

I have a problem with the code because it does not work as it should. This part of the code works when it perform on first player

```
@EventHandler
public void onMove(PlayerMoveEvent event) {
    Player player = event.getPlayer();
    if (plugin.getPlayerEvent(player).equals("spleef")) {
        if (plugin.getInfo().eventstarted) {
            Material b = player.getLocation().getBlock().getType();
            if (b.equals(Material.STATIONARY_WATER) || b.equals(Material.WATER) || event.getPlayer().getLocation().getY() <= 0) {
                if (!lul.contains(player.getName()) && !ended) {
                    ended = true;
                    lul.add(player.getName());
                    plugin.getMethods().basicLose(player);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When the second player touches the water nothing happens. There are no errors. Here is the whole code:

```
package Handlers.EventHandlers.SimpleEvents;

import Mains.MiniEvents;
import org.bukkit.*;
import org.bukkit.block.Block;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.event.EventHandler;
import org.bukkit.event.Listener;
import org.bukkit.event.block.BlockBreakEvent;
import org.bukkit.event.player.PlayerMoveEvent;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;

public class Spleef implements Listener {
    public final ArrayList<Location> block = new ArrayList<>();
    public final ArrayList<Location> block2 = new ArrayList<>();
    public static final HashSet<String> lul = new HashSet<>();
    public MiniEvents plugin;

    public Spleef(MiniEvents plugin) {
        this.plugin = plugin;
    }

    @EventHandler
    public void onBreak(final BlockBreakEvent event) {
        final Player player = event.getPlayer();
        if (plugin.getPlayerEvent(player).equals("spleef")) {
            if (plugin.getInfo().sbefore.contains(event.getPlayer().getName())) {
                event.setCancelled(true);
            } else {
                final Block b = event.getBlock();
                if (player.getItemInHand() != null && !player.getItemInHand().getType().equals(Material.AIR)) {
                    if (b.getType().equals(Material.SNOW_BLOCK)) {
                        event.setCancelled(true);
                        player.getWorld().playEffect(b.getLocation(), Effect.STEP_SOUND, 80);
                        b.setType(Material.AIR);
                        block.add(b.getLocation());
                        block2.add(b.getLocation());
                    } else {
                        event.setCancelled(true);
                    }
                } else {
                    event.setCancelled(true);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static boolean ended = false;

    @EventHandler
    public void onMove(PlayerMoveEvent event) {
        Player player = event.getPlayer();
        if (plugin.getPlayerEvent(player).equals("spleef")) {
            if (plugin.getInfo().eventstarted) {
                Material b = player.getLocation().getBlock().getType();
                if (b.equals(Material.STATIONARY_WATER) || b.equals(Material.WATER) || event.getPlayer().getLocation().getY() <= 0) {
                    if (!lul.contains(player.getName()) && !ended) {
                        ended = true;
                        lul.add(player.getName());
                        plugin.getMethods().basicLose(player);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm pretty sure 'ended' is true at the second player so it won't do it.

Comment: Could you please indent your code correctly?

Comment: `ended` is a static variable. The first player sets `ended` to true, so the condition `&& !ended` will always evaluate to false for subsequent players.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because of the boolean `ended`, which you set to true, but can never be re-set to false. So, execution for the code stops here:

```
if (!lul.contains(player.getName()) && !ended) {
```

because `ended` is now true.

To fix this, you could use a `HashMap`, a `HashMap` stores values, for keys. You have to make sure you never store Player objects in HashMaps, though, as it will cause memory leaks when the player leaves, so, you should use the player's UUID instead (you could also use their name, but it may cause errors if the player's username changes in 1.8):

```
Map<UUID, Boolean> ended = new HashMap<UUID, Boolean>();
```

to get the value, you could do:

```
ended.get(player.getUniqueId();
```

Make sure that you check if the HashMap contains a key before you get it, though, or you may get a NullPointerException:

```
if(ended.containsKey(player.getUniqueId())
```

to put a value into the map, you could use:

```
ended.put(player.getUniqueId(), boolean);
```

So, here's what your event should look like:

```
public static Map<UUID, Boolean> ended = new HashMap<UUID, Boolean>();

@EventHandler
public void onMove(PlayerMoveEvent event) {
    Player player = event.getPlayer();
    if (plugin.getPlayerEvent(player).equals("spleef")) {
        if (plugin.getInfo().eventstarted) {
            Material b = player.getLocation().getBlock().getType();
            if (b.equals(Material.STATIONARY_WATER) || b.equals(Material.WATER) || event.getPlayer().getLocation().getY() <= 0) {
                boolean end = false;
                if(ended.containsKey(player.getUniqueId()){
                    end = ended.get(player.getUniqueId();
                }
                //else{} we don't want to do anything if ended does not contain the player's UUID!
                if (!lul.contains(player.getName()) && !end){
                    ended.put(player.getUniqueId(), true);
                    lul.add(player.getName());
                    plugin.getMethods().basicLose(player);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```